# Geoapify Geocoder Autocomplete placeSelect no esta funcionando correctamente con react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, geojson

Estoy usando el componente para automcompletar direcciones con la API @geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete en un proyecto en React.
Ya me baje las librerías (downloaded geoapify/autocomplete y geoapify/react-autocomplete) y seguí los tutoriales de la documentación pero pareciera que placeSelect no esta funcionando

geoapify repo:  https://github.com/geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete

Intente reinstalar las dependencias, reiniciar toda la compu, pero sigue sin aparecer nada en la consola.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete,
    GeoapifyContext
} from "@geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete"; 
import "@geoapify/geocoder-autocomplete/styles/round-borders.css";

const API_KEY = "xxx";

export default function Autocomplete() {
    const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

    function onPlaceSelect(data) {
        setInfo(data);
        console.log(info);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <GeoapifyContext apiKey={API_KEY}>
                <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete
                    placeSelect={onPlaceSelect}
                    placeholder="Ingresá una ciudad"
                    allowNonVerifiedHouseNumber={true}
                    allowNonVerifiedStreet={true}
                />
            </GeoapifyContext>
            <section>
                <h2>Output</h2>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Tambien intente inicializar el useState en otro valor, y que lo muestre en pantalla pero nunca se actualizó. Pareciera que nunca llego a ejecutarse el onPlaceSelect?
Alguien más ya tuvo este problema?

Cualquier ayuda será agradecida eternamente.

Comment: Bienvenido. Este sitio está en español. Traduce tu pregunta o ve a [so].

Comment: Hola! Pregunta traducida, perdon! No me habia dado cuenta que estaba en stackOverflow en español

Comment: Coloca el `console.log` afuera de la función `onPlaceSelect`, en teoría deberías ver datos después del re-render.